# Setup an ALB to re-route to a different target group if all checks are failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are trying to put up a maintenance webpage for our customers, when our application is down for whatever reason.

Say we have an Application Load Balancer on AWS.

How do we setup an ALB to re-route to a different target group if all checks are failing? Say there are 2 target groups, one is the "primary" target group. And if all instances in that TG are unhealthy, is there a way to then route to a different target group, or a different URL or something?

Comment: The purpose of an ASG is to route to the healthy members of a single target group.

Comment: What is an ASG? that acronym was not spelled out in the OP so I surprised you'd drop that without an explanation

Comment: I assume you mean "auto-scaling groups" and I don't see how that pertains to the question - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html

Comment: Sorry, I meant ALB not ASG.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought, just wasn't sure, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such feature in ALB or in AS group, but you can try to explore Rout53.

**Configuring DNS failover**

> If you have multiple resources that perform the same function, you can
>   configure DNS failover so that Route 53 will route your traffic from
>   an **unhealthy** resource to a **healthy** resource. For example, if you have
>   two web servers and one web server becomes unhealthy, Route 53 can
>   route traffic to the other web server. For more information, see
>   [Configuring DNS Failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-configuring.html).

**[Evaluate the health of an AWS resource (alias records)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-simple-configs.html)**

> If you're using alias records to route traffic to selected AWS
>   resources, such as ELB load balancers, you can configure Route 53 to
>   evaluate the health of the resource and to route traffic only to
>   resources that are healthy. When you configure an alias record to
>   evaluate the health of a resource, you don't need to create a health
>   check for the resource.

Comment: thanks, upvoted ..such a missing feature is pretty silly isn't it? seems like a popular need idk